# Derivative of $\sec^{-1}u$ and $\csc ^{-1}u$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

How to get the derivative of $$\sec^{-1}u$$
and $$\csc^{-1}u$$
I wrote it as $$\sec m=u$$
Then take derivative with respect to $x$ of both side we have 
$$\sec m \tan m \dfrac{dm}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dx}$$
Then $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1}u=\dfrac{dm}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\sec m \tan m}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\pm\dfrac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\dfrac{du}{dx}----(1)$$
Use the same method we have 
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\csc^{-1}u=\pm\dfrac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\dfrac{du}{dx}----(2)$$
I got these result, but I am not sure how to write the $\pm$ separately.

The solution said for $(1)$, when $u>1$, we have the sign $+$, when $u<-1$, we have the sign $-$.

For $(2)$,  when $u>1$, we have the sign $-$, when $u<-1$, we have the sign $+$.

Answer (score 1):

The sign depends on the choice of domain of $\sec$, which varies by
textbook.  Look at the graph of $\sec^{-1} x$ for whatever choice of
domain you have.  Choose the sign of the derivative according to 
whether the graph is increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

For $u>1$ or for $u<-1$

$$\sec^{-1}u+\csc^{-1}u=\dfrac\pi2$$